# No Text selection tool in Kile with Okular as reader

Tags: tools, kile, okular

I'm using `Kile` as my LaTeX IDE with `Okular` as pdf viewer.
Everything works fine except the fact that I cannot find the text selection tool to copy text from the previewed pdf.
I know that this tool exists in Okular but I can't figure out to find it. The only tool that I have is the browse tool which doesn't allow to copy text.

EDIT: As cfr pointed out, I'm talking of the mini-previews Kile provides.

Comment: Have you set Okular to being embedded in Kile, or a separate window?

Comment: When you talk about the previewed PDF, have you compiled? Or are you talking about the mini-previews Kile can produce beforehand? If so, I doubt you can select text in those cases, though I'm not certain.

Comment: Okular is embedded in Kile.

Answer (score 1):

Okular has a "Tools" menu with entries "Selection Tool", "Text Selection Tool", "Table Selection Tool". All these three tools select text in different ways -- try them out. Then hit Ctrl+C to copy the selected text. These tools also have a toolbar button (probably the last one) with a dropdown arrow to select between them.

Comment: I guess that the OP wants to select text and copy it from Okular.

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to Okular; I will correct my answer.

Comment: I know these tools and if I start Okular outside of Kile I even find them and can use them. But inside Kile I can't find this dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what Okular looks like from inside Kile. If you can't see the menus or toolbars, you can change 'mode' with Ctrl-#:

- Ctrl-3: selection mode
- Ctrl-4: text-selection mode
- Ctrl-5: table-selection mode

Comment: These shortcuts don't seem to work when I use them into the pdf preview that Kile shows me.